# Parse JSON object

Tags: php, json

How i can loop on "data" array and get the values of "code" without knowing the name of the instance because it's changing. Thanks

```
"response": {
    "status": 1,
    "httpStatus": 200,
    "data": [
      {
        "offer_id": "24",
        "countries": {
          "ES": {
            "id": "724",
            **"code": "ES",**
            "name": "Spain",
            "regions": []
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "errors": [],
    "errorMessage": null
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you speaking of "response" to be changing? If you do not know anything but the structure you could do a _json\_decode()_ to transform the json object string into a php array, loop thru this array and its sub-arrays (hint: _is\_array()_) and extract the second item of the only one fourth (?) level array.

Answer (score 0):

your data is coming in json format than you can do something like below
if your data is coming through some variable you can decode it like below

```
$array = json_decode($result,true);
```

where your json result is in `$result` and the whole array is in `$array`

hope it will help you,

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand that you will not be sure of the key that holds that code 
as in your example it is "ES" in others it might be "US" etc

1. You can use json_decode($json, true) to get this string as a php array and then loop over the data key: something like this

`

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);
$data = $jsonArray['response']['data']; 



$countryCodes = [];
foreach ($data as $datum) {
    if (isset($datum['countries'])) {
        foreach ($datum['countries'] as $key => $value) {
            $countryCodes[$key] = $value['code']; // $key is also code
            // so maybe $countryCodes[$key] = $value['name'];
        }
    }
}

print_r($countryCodes); // array of codes
```

`

2. You can take the response as a string and then use regex to get the code

Comment: You have an idea how to do it using regex? the foreach didn't worked

Comment: @RamiDarawi 1. What do you get when you do ` $jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);` in the $jsonArray.
2. From where are you getting this data? If through an API doesn't it support getting the "code" directly?

Comment: 1. I printed it, I get the data as i posted previously. 2. Unfortunately, no

Comment: @RamiDarawi You have posted the JSON(which also misses an initial brace), Please post the result that you got after decoding it to PHP array. Just wanted to make sure that it really gets converted to an array